# Incorrect percentages of languages in a GitHub repository

Tags: html, r, github

In one of my GitHub repositories, the following percentages of languages used are shown:

[image: percentages]

However, there shouldn't be any HTML codes since I don't write any! The repo contains mainly `R` codes and a few `TeX` codes.  But GitHub shows that 59% of my repository is filled with HTML codes. Surprisingly enough, when I click on there it shows the following:

[image]

The `R` and `TeX` files are being appropriately shown:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: Without looking at your repository, there's no easy way to tell where does the 59.3% comes from. You can however try to run [github-linguist](https://github.com/github-linguist/linguist) locally to know exactly how

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately I won't be able to make this repository public right now. But I'lll surely have a look at what you suggested.